# Error 405 when opening project having Open Weather API via Github pages

Tags: node.js, express, github, http-status-code-405

**My app.js**

```
    const express = require ("express"); 
    const res = require("express/lib/response");
    const https = require ("https");
    const bodyParser = require ("body-parser");
    
    const app = express(); 
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    
    app.get("/",function(request, response){ 
        response.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
    }) 
    
    app.post("/", function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body.cityName);
        // console.log("POST request received.");
        const query=req.body.cityName;
        const apiKey="796ea31271937af05a23079696c29758";
        const units = "metric";
        const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+query+"&appid="+apiKey+"&units="+units;
        https.get(url, function(response){
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            response.on("data", function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                const weatherData= JSON.parse(data);
                    // console.log(weatherData);
                    // const object = {
                    //     name: "Ann",
                    //     favouriteFood: "Butter Chicken"
                    // }
                    // console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
                const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
                console.log("Temperature : "+temp);
                const feelsLike = weatherData.main.feels_like;
                console.log("Feels like : "+feelsLike);
                const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;
                console.log("Weather Description : "+weatherDescription);
                const icon= weatherData.weather[0].icon;
                imageURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+icon+"@2x.png"
                    // Method 1
                    //response.send("<h2>The temperature in Montreal, Quebec is "+temp+" degrees Celcius.</h2><br><h2>The weather is currently "+weatherDescription+"</h2><br><h2>The feels like temperature is "+feelsLike+" degrees Celcius. </h2>")
                    // Method 2
                res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
                res.write("<h2>The temperature in "+query+" is "+temp+" degrees Celcius.</h2>")
                res.write("<p>The weather is currently "+weatherDescription+"</p>")
                res.write("<h4>The feels like temperature is "+feelsLike+" degrees Celcius. </h4>")
                res.write("<img src="+imageURL+">");
                res.send();
            });
        });        
    })
    
    
    
    app.listen(3000, function(){ 
        console.log("Server is running on port 3000."); 
    })
```

**My index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Weather Project</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form action="/" method="post">
          <label for="city-input">City Name: </label>
          <input id="city-input" type="text" name="cityName" />
          <button type="submit">Go</button>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When I test this app.js on my local server it shows the expected response, i.e. the temperature of the city that I send in POST request. But when I run the project using my Github pages link it shows the index.html but when I send the city as POST request,I get a 405 error on the next page. I am new so I am not sure what is wrong but my initial thought was that it is something related to the API key? as in the key ID?
Please help.

Comment: Thank you for this. So basically I can't host it on Github as it supports no server side technologies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like github repo doesn't support the post requests. Did you try using the different hosting platform like firebase?